# How to fix infinite loop in python

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi3, infinite

I just started with python and RPi. But i stuck :D
I have 4 microswitches, and few posibilities (BC1, BC2, BC3... etc). For example, if we choose posibility BC1, then microswitch 1 (btn1) and 2 (btn2) must be active, if that case is true, then ledG1 and vazduh are active. Also I need to have a posibiliti to insert another posibiliti (BC1, BC2, BC3), and untill we insert another posibility first must be active (if requested switches are active).

With this code it's working, but ask me only once to insert possibility.

```py
BC1 = '1'
BC2 = '2'
BC3 = '3'
BC4 = '4'
BC5 = '5'

def compare ():
    while True:
        Barcode = input("Insert barcode: ")
        while Barcode == BC1:
            if GPIO.input(btn1)==0 and GPIO.input(btn2)==0:
                GPIO.output(vazduh, GPIO.HIGH)
                GPIO.output(ledG1, GPIO.HIGH)
                continue
            else:
                GPIO.output(vazduh, GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(ledG1, GPIO.LOW)
                continue                
        while Barcode == BC2:
            if GPIO.input(btn2)==0 and GPIO.input(btn4)==0:
                GPIO.output(vazduh, GPIO.HIGH)
                GPIO.output(ledG3, GPIO.HIGH)
                continue
            else:
                GPIO.output(vazduh, GPIO.LOW)
                GPIO.output(ledG3, GPIO.LOW)
                continue


compare ()
```

Comment: You don't `break`  out of any of your `while` loops

Comment: I tried with break after else, after that constantly request to input variant. But when i press switches it don't work. It's working only if I frist press requested switches and after that input variant for that switches (but that is not wahat I need)

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably wanted to use `if` instead of `while` in your first while's scope.

```
while True:
   Barcode = input("Insert barcode: ")
   if Barcode == BC1:
      #Do something #1
   if Barcode == BC2:
      #Do something #2
```

Comment: @VizslaLover Can you elaborate more? Can you print anything after getting the input from the user? maybe the problem is not with the loops.

Comment: Sorry, when I tried with IF, it's same as i tried wit break after else. When I tried with IF it constantly request to input variant. But when i press switches it don't work. It's working only if I frist press requested switches and after that input variant for that switches (but that is not wahat I need)

Comment: @VizslaLover Are you using Raspberry Pi's built in push buttons or are you using different buttons? I suspect your problem might be with the hardware and how you read it. From what I remember, since buttons are mechanical, they are a bit laggy and are not as fast as digital buttons. You have to wait a bit after reading your ports data.

Comment: I use push buttons, and it works with code on beginning. But with that code it ask me only first time for variant. And for insertion other variant i need to run code again. And I need to have possibility to insert variant all the time.